# Can't boot into Windows 10 through grub after dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, bios

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with Windows 10, at first, Windows entry did not show in grub menu, so I did the following:

Added this lines to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root=(hd0,1)
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set (partition uuid)
    chainloader +1
}
```

That didn't work. Even though I am able to boot by BIOS. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your grub attempt is for a legacy install of Windows, but Windows machines have been delivered from the manfacturer in UEFI mode for about 10 years. Still, an upgrade from Win7 might leave Windows in legacy mode.  What type of partitioning does your disk have? gpt=> UEFI, dos=>legacy.  How you install Ubuntu (legacy vs UEFI) is how you boot your install media, and that is controlled by your machine settings. Both Windows and Ubuntu should be installed in the same mode.

Comment: It's GPT. What should I change in the command, then? I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: If it's GPT then UEFI. Boot Windows directly, disable Fast Startup. Shutdown. Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. There should never be a need to edit manually.

Comment: If doing the above does not produce: 
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi for the Windows boot (or produces nothing) you probably have the grub-pc package instead of grub-efi, so you should install grub-efi to successfully run update-grub, or just reinsatll Ubuntu after you figure out what machine settings will boot your USB in UEFI mode.